# Read JSON file from Firebase Storage using Admin SDK in Python without download

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am growing through Python, to read a JSON file present on Firebase Storage via the admin sdk. I have already read the following question

[How to download file from firebase storage in python using firebase_admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70107431/how-to-download-file-from-firebase-storage-in-python-using-firebase-admin)

but in this case the file is downloaded to another file. Is it possible instead to read it without downloading it and without making it public? Or alternatively is it possible to make a temporary file and once python prints it deletes it? Thank you

My code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, storage
cred = credentials.Certificate('serviceAccount.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    "storageBucket": "**.appspot.com"
})
source_blob_name = "UQ4ADY.json"
#The path to which the file should be downloaded
destination_file_name = r"temp\ftmp.json"

bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
```

Be aware that there may be a lot of requests and that is why I prefer not to download the files

Comment: Read the object into memory **download_as_string()**, then print the string.

Comment: Perfect, it works but I used `download_as_text` so I can convert it to json. If you submit this comment as an answer I sign it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

After a comment by Johm Hanley, i used `download_as_text` funcion:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, storage
cred = credentials.Certificate('serviceAccount.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    "storageBucket": "**.appspot.com"
})
source_blob_name = "UQ4ADY.json"
#The path to which the file should be downloaded
destination_file_name = r"temp\ftmp.json"

bucket = storage.bucket()
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
data = blob.download_as_text()
```